# I constantly get a 'http://localhost:3000/test 404 (Not Found)'

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I constantly get a 'http://localhost:3000/test 404 (Not Found)' when I launch my application which is supposed to launch node queries.
I don't understand why. I'm working on a React app with a mySQL database (from the Mysql app) and I'm using node to create an API. I have created a very simple database with two columns 'username' and 'password'.

The operation is supposed to be simple by clicking on a button I must have the request of my api that appears in the console.

I used the '/test' route because it already exists in my React app.
I would like to point out that I changed the name of the port for the api but it didn't change anything and that I can read my database in my terminal very well so the api succeeded in connecting with mysql.

Below my api and my react/node code thanks in advance for your help.

**API**

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'XXX',
  database: 'reactapp'
});

connection.query('SELECT * FROM user', function(err, results, fields) {
  console.log(results);
});

const PORT = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(cors());


app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  connection.query('SELECT username FROM user', (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send('Erreur interne du serveur');
    } else {
      const usernames = results.map((row) => row.username);
      console.log(usernames);
      res.send('Usernames affichés dans la console');
    }
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**REACT/NODE**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class Button extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    axios.get('/test')
      .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Afficher les données</button>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

**Package**

I have already installed a proxy in the following way because the app is created in react app:

```
   { "name": "management-app", 
"version": "0.1.0", 
"private": true, 
"proxy": "localhost:3000", 
"dependencies": { // ... }, 
"scripts": { // ... }, // ... }
```

Comment: How are you running your React app? What port is it running on? Did you make it using `create-react-app` and if so, did you configure a `proxy` setting in `package.json`?

Comment: I have already installed a proxy in the following way because the app is created in react app: "{
  "name": "management-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide those details. Code does not belong in the comments

Comment: I'll ask again, how are you running your React app?

Comment: using create-react-app

Comment: That's how you created it but **how do you run it?** Do you use `npm run dev` or something else? When you open it in your browser, what URL is in the location bar?

Comment: Looks like your `proxy` config is simply missing the `http://` prefix